# tengo un problema de redireccionamiento con javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Buenos días tardes o noches
tengo un pequeño problema al tratar de redireccionar mi aplicación desde mi ventana de login a la ventana de usuario, este es mi código de javascript:

```
(function () {
    document.clean = function(){
        document.getElementById("code").value = "";
        document.getElementById("pass").value = "";
    };

    document.redirect = function(){
        try{
            var inputCode = parseInt(document.getElementById("code").value);
            var inputPass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
            var baseUser = {
                codigo: 506151060,
                password: "h3lctcep0"
            };
            var route = './MateoBlanco/pages/User.html';
            if (inputCode == baseUser.codigo && inputPass == baseUser.password) {
                document.location.href = route;
                debugger;
            } else {
                alert("datos erróneos");
                document.location.reload();
            }
        }catch(ex){
            console.log(ex);
        }
    };
})();
```

podrían por favor decirme ¿porqué no redirecciona?
gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Comment: utilizad `window.location` y las rutas a redireccionar deben incluir el `http://` o `https://`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.location` es un objeto que contiene todas las propiedades de la ubicación actual, como `protocol`, `host` o `pathname`.

La propiedad `href` es una de estas propiedades, que contiene la URL completa, es decir, todas las demás propiedades juntas.

Sin embargo, `document` es una propiedad de **sólo lectura** por lo que lo recomendable es usar `window.location`, y específicamente, la propiedad `href`.

Así, por ejemplo, para redireccionar a esta página escribirías algo como esto:

`window.location.href = https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/302912/tengo-un-problema-de-redireccionamiento-con-javascript`